# How can I compute the autocorrelation of a sample using Math.NET

Tags: math.net

Apparently Math.Net library does not contain a function for obtaining the autocorrelation of a sample.

How can this be achievied using the same library?

Comment: Please take a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419323/cross-correlation-using-mathdotnet-c-sharp/47389474#47389474). It includes both, cross and auto correlation.

Answer (score 3):

The function:

```
double ACF<T>(IEnumerable<T> series, int lag, Func<T, double> f)
```

in
[MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Mcmc](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Mcmc/MCMCDiagnostics.htm)

calculates an autocorrelation.

An example of using it is in the [unit test](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/UnitTests/StatisticsTests/MCMCTests/MCMCDiagnosticsTest.cs).

A snippet from it is:

```
var series = new double[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{ series[i] = RandomSeries(); }

double result = MCMCDiagnostics.ACF(series, lag, x=>x*x);
```